# How to close the TcpListener before the client logged in? c#

Tags: c#

> How to close the TcpListener before the client logged in?

I have this Stop button on my server class:

```
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            client.GetStream().Close();
            client.Close();       
            server.Stop();
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

the problem is that if I open the server and after I click "Stop" before that client is connect I get exception:

`System.NullReferenceException`

I tried to add `if(!client.Connected){client.GetStream().Close();client.Close(); }`  but then I get the same exception.

Should I write `if(!client!=null)...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NullReferenceException occurs when you try to use a method or property of a reference type whose value is null.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxw2ez55.aspx

So, yes, check if `client` is null.

```
if (client != null)
{
    client.Close();
}
```